# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows') when replacing ListView with FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist, react-native-listview, react-native-sectionlist

I'm updating a project to react-native 62+ from 50~, and ListView was removed from react-native, and so I'm trying to change the ListView in this file to a FlatList. I don't know what to do with datasource to properly manage the data. Can somebody help me upgrade this file?

This is the original code using the ListView without any of my attempts at upgrading, which gives "Invariant Error: ListView has been removed from React-Native": (my attempted code below)

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  ListView,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
} from 'react-native';

import PoplarEnv from '../util/PoplarEnv';
import CommentCell from './CommentCell';
import {getCommentsOfObject} from '../api/CommentAPI';
import URLConf from '../api/URLConf';

const avatar_thumbnail = '?imageView2/1/w/48/h/48';

export default class CommentList extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      loaded: false,
      replyModalVisible: false,
      commentsArray: [],
      commentCounter: this.props.commentCounter,
      commented: this.props.commented,
      limit: this.props.limit, //评论显示行数

      comment: null,
      commentBarVisible: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();

  }

  /*
    被评论的feed类型
  */
  getCommentObjType(type) {
    var type_str = '';
    switch (type) {
      case PoplarEnv.COMMENT_OBJ_TYPE.POST:
        type_str = 'post';
        break;
      case PoplarEnv.COMMENT_OBJ_TYPE.PHOTO:
        type_str = 'photo';
        break;
      case PoplarEnv.COMMENT_OBJ_TYPE.ALBUM:
        type_str = 'album';
        break;
      case PoplarEnv.COMMENT_OBJ_TYPE.SPOST:
        type_str = 'spost';
        break;
      default:
        type_str = '';

    }
    return type_str;
  }

  fetchData() {
    var type_str = this.getCommentObjType(this.props.object_type);
    getCommentsOfObject(type_str, this.props.object_id,this.state.limit, (result, comments) => {
      this.setState({
        commentsArray: comments,
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(comments),
        loaded: true,
      });
    });
  }

  renderLoadingView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Loading...
        </Text>
      </View>

    );
  }


  setReplyModalVisible() {
    this.setState({replyModalVisible: true});
  }

  setReplyModalInVisible() {
    this.setState({replyModalVisible: false});
  }

  addNewComment(comment) {
    console.log('add new comment to comments list');
    console.log(comment);
    var commentsArray = this.state.commentsArray;
    commentsArray.push(comment);

    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(commentsArray),
    });

  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if(this.props.commentCounter == nextProps.commentCounter) return;

    if(nextProps.newComment != undefined && nextProps.newComment != null) {
        this.addNewComment(nextProps.newComment);
    }
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }
    return this.renderCommentList(this.props.commentCounter);
  }


  showCommentBar() {
    this.setState({
      commentBarVisible: true,
    });
  }

  hideCommentBar() {
    this.setState({
      isComment: false,
      commentBarVisible: false,
    });
  }


  renderCommentList(commentCounter) {

    if(commentCounter > 0) {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.commentList} onPress={this.props.nav2FeedDetail}>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(comment)=>this.renderRow(comment, this.props.caller)}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    } else {
      return (<View/>);
    }

  }

  renderAuthorName(comment) {
    if(comment.comment_parent_author_name != undefined && comment.comment_parent_author_name != null) {
      return (<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Text style={styles.username}>{comment.comment_author_name}</Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 14, color: '#9B9B9B', bottom: 1}}> Reply </Text>
                <Text style={styles.username}>{comment.comment_parent_author_name}</Text>
              </View>
            );
    } else {
      return (<Text style={styles.username}>{comment.comment_author_name}</Text>);
    }

  }

  renderRow(comment, caller) {
    if(comment == null || comment == undefined) {
      return (<View />);
    } else {
      if(caller == 'FeedCell') {
        return(
              <View style={styles.commentBox}>
                <Image style={styles.avatar} source={{uri:URLConf.IMG_BASE_URL+comment.comment_author_avatar+avatar_thumbnail}} />
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    {this.renderAuthorName(comment)}
                    <Text style={styles.comment}>{comment.comment_content}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
        );
      } else if(caller == 'FeedDetail') {
        return(
          <CommentCell comment={comment} reply={this.props.reply}/>
        );
      }
    }
  }
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  commentList: {
    marginTop: -10,
    marginLeft:8,
    marginRight:8,
    paddingTop: 0,
  },
  commentBox: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    //borderColor: 'black',
    //borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    paddingBottom: 4,
  },
  avatar: {
    borderRadius: 16,
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  username: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'black',
    // lineHeight: 13,
    marginBottom: 4,
  },
  commentTime: {

  },
  comment: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#030303',
    lineHeight: 18,
  },
});

module.exports = CommentList;
```

This is the code of my attempt at upgrading it, but I get this error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows')" on line 78 "dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(comments),"

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  //ListView,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
} from 'react-native';

import PoplarEnv from '../util/PoplarEnv';
import CommentCell from './CommentCell';
import {getCommentsOfObject} from '../api/CommentAPI';
import URLConf from '../api/URLConf';

const avatar_thumbnail = '?imageView2/1/w/48/h/48';

export default class CommentList extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
      //   rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      // }),
      loaded: false,
      replyModalVisible: false,
      commentsArray: [],
      commentCounter: this.props.commentCounter,
      commented: this.props.commented,
      limit: this.props.limit, //评论显示行数

      comment: null,
      commentBarVisible: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();

  }

  /*
    被评论的feed类型
  */
  getCommentObjType(type) {
    var type_str = '';
    switch (type) {
      case PoplarEnv.COMMENT_OBJ_TYPE.POST:
        type_str = 'post';
        break;
      case PoplarEnv.COMMENT_OBJ_TYPE.PHOTO:
        type_str = 'photo';
        break;
      case PoplarEnv.COMMENT_OBJ_TYPE.ALBUM:
        type_str = 'album';
        break;
      case PoplarEnv.COMMENT_OBJ_TYPE.SPOST:
        type_str = 'spost';
        break;
      default:
        type_str = '';

    }
    return type_str;
  }

  fetchData() {
    var type_str = this.getCommentObjType(this.props.object_type);
    getCommentsOfObject(type_str, this.props.object_id,this.state.limit, (result, comments) => {
      this.setState({
        commentsArray: comments,
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(comments),
        loaded: true,
      });
    });
  }

  renderLoadingView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Loading...
        </Text>
      </View>

    );
  }


  setReplyModalVisible() {
    this.setState({replyModalVisible: true});
  }

  setReplyModalInVisible() {
    this.setState({replyModalVisible: false});
  }

  addNewComment(comment) {
    console.log('add new comment to comments list');
    console.log(comment);
    var commentsArray = this.state.commentsArray;
    commentsArray.push(comment);

    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(commentsArray),
    });

  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if(this.props.commentCounter == nextProps.commentCounter) return;

    if(nextProps.newComment != undefined && nextProps.newComment != null) {
        this.addNewComment(nextProps.newComment);
    }
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }
    return this.renderCommentList(this.props.commentCounter);
  }


  showCommentBar() {
    this.setState({
      commentBarVisible: true,
    });
  }

  hideCommentBar() {
    this.setState({
      isComment: false,
      commentBarVisible: false,
    });
  }


  renderCommentList(commentCounter) {

    if(commentCounter > 0) {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.commentList} onPress={this.props.nav2FeedDetail}>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            extraData={this.state}
            renderItem={(comment)=>this.renderRow(comment, this.props.caller)}
          />
          {/* <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(comment)=>this.renderRow(comment, this.props.caller)}
          /> */}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    } else {
      return (<View/>);
    }

  }

  renderAuthorName(comment) {
    if(comment.comment_parent_author_name != undefined && comment.comment_parent_author_name != null) {
      return (<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <Text style={styles.username}>{comment.comment_author_name}</Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 14, color: '#9B9B9B', bottom: 1}}> Reply </Text>
                <Text style={styles.username}>{comment.comment_parent_author_name}</Text>
              </View>
            );
    } else {
      return (<Text style={styles.username}>{comment.comment_author_name}</Text>);
    }

  }

  renderRow(comment, caller) {
    if(comment == null || comment == undefined) {
      return (<View />);
    } else {
      if(caller == 'FeedCell') {
        return(
              <View style={styles.commentBox}>
                <Image style={styles.avatar} source={{uri:URLConf.IMG_BASE_URL+comment.comment_author_avatar+avatar_thumbnail}} />
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    {this.renderAuthorName(comment)}
                    <Text style={styles.comment}>{comment.comment_content}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
        );
      } else if(caller == 'FeedDetail') {
        return(
          <CommentCell comment={comment} reply={this.props.reply}/>
        );
      }
    }
  }
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  commentList: {
    marginTop: -10,
    marginLeft:8,
    marginRight:8,
    paddingTop: 0,
  },
  commentBox: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    //borderColor: 'black',
    //borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    paddingBottom: 4,
  },
  avatar: {
    borderRadius: 16,
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  username: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'black',
    // lineHeight: 13,
    marginBottom: 4,
  },
  commentTime: {

  },
  comment: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#030303',
    lineHeight: 18,
  },
});

module.exports = CommentList;
```

If you need any more code, like CommentCell or FeedCell, just let me know and I'll edit the post to add the code. Can somebody please help me with this, I've spent hours on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to totally change `ListView` to `Flatlist`.

So first import `Flatlist` from the `react-native` :

```js
import { FlatList } from "react-native";
```

Then change `ListView` to `Flatlist` as below :

```js
renderCommentList(commentCounter) {
  if(commentCounter > 0) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.commentList} onPress={this.props.nav2FeedDetail}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          extraData={this.state}
          renderItem={({ item })=>this.renderRow(item, this.props.caller)}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  } else {
    return (<View/>);
  }
}
```

You can find more documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist)

**Update**

Your `dataSource` state variable should be simple array like this :

```js
this.state = {
  dataSource: []
}
```

Then when you fetch the data, append your data in dataSource state variable like this :

```
this.setState({
  commentsArray: comments,
  dataSource: comments,
  loaded: true,
});
```

**Note : **Your `renderItems` method should be as below :

```js
renderItem={({ comment })=>this.renderRow(comment, this.props.caller)}
```

`comment` should be in {} braces.

Comment: I've updated the post with my new code and error, I tried what you said and I'm getting the error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows')". Do you know how I should update the lines that use "cloneWithRows" that are giving this error?

Comment: Great, that seemed to get rid of the errors. Now I just need to figure out why the comments list is blank(just white where the comments should be) in the simulator after each comment cell (renderItem/Row) is rendered, even with the correct data(I checked). Should print to the sim but they're not there, it's strange. Thanks!